# SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager: Unable to view columns in tables added to View designer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL Server 2000 database that will not display the column list for any tables in the View "designer" in Enterprise Manager  This problem exists when either designing a new view or when editing existing views.  All that is displayed for each table in the diagram is "* (All Columns)".  The views otherwise work.

I do NOT have this problem with any other databases.

I ran DBCC CHECKDB on this database and it reported 0 errors.

The SQL Server Log files do not report any errors other than "Error: 15457, Severity: 0, State: 1" which, IIRC, is not really an error and has nothing to do with this problem.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Yes. I am logged in as sa.
I just realized that this database has "." in its name. I'm betting this has something to do with the problem. (I received the database from a customer)

Comment: yes, perhaps try restoring the database with a different name that doens't have the "."

Comment: Thanks !  I did that and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(cough) um ... this appears to be a bug in Enterprise Manager that happens when the database name has a full stop in it.

Check whether the database name has a full stop (".") in it, and if it has, restore the database with a different name, omitting the full stop.

(answer gleaned from the comment conversation above)